# JavaScript regex get all numbers but exclude all between brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, brackets

I have string:

`123 df456 555 [ 789   ] [abc 1011 def ] [ ghi 1213] [jkl mno 1415 pqr] 161718 jkl 1920`

I need to get only numbers, that don't placed between `square brackets [ ]`.
All the resulted numbers I need to place inside `square brackets [ ]`
The correct result should be:

`[123] df456 [555] [ 789   ] [abc 1011 def ] [ ghi 1213] [jkl mno 1415 pqr] [161718] jkl [1920]`

I've tried to write such JavaScript regex:
`/(?!\[(.*?)\])((\s|^)(\d+?)(\s|$))/ig`

but it seems to be wrong, it seems like positive lookahead has more priority than negative lookahead.

Comment: SORRY, BUT ALSO all the numbers from a result I need to place inside square brackets.
The final result should be:
[1234] [ blabla 101112 ] [67890] [113141516 ] bla171819 [212123]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming square brackets are balanced and un-nested, you can also use a negative lookahead to grab numbers outside `[...]`:

```js
var str = '1232 [dfgdfgsdf 45] 1234 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123';
var re = /\b\d+\b(?![^[]*\])/g;

var repl = str.replace(re, "[$&]");

console.log(repl);
//=> [1232] [dfgdfgsdf 45] [1234] [ blabla 101112 ] [67890] [113141516 ] bla171819 [212123]
```

This regex match any number that doesn't have `]` ahead without matching `[`.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b             # word boundary
\d+            # match 1 or more digits
\b             # word boundary
(?!            # negative lookahead start
   [^[]*       # match 0 or more of any character that is not literal "["
   \]          # match literal ]
)              # lookahead end
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mUf301/1)

Comment: This case (not from question, but in my work) doesn't works (number nested to ] ):
str5 = "1232 [dfgdfgsdf 45]";
str5.replace(/\b\d+\b(?![^][]*\])/g,"[$1]");

Comment: Ah that's right, there was a minor tweak required. Check my updated answer with a regex demo now.

Answer (score 2):

Match all substrings between `[` and `]` and match *and capture* those others that are whole words (inside word boundaries):

```
/\[[^\][]*\]|\b(\d+)\b/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV58ik/2) and a demo code below.

*Details*:

- `\[[^\][]*\]` - `[`, then 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`, and a `]`
- `|` - or
- `\b` - leading word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing one or more digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary
- `/g` - global, multiple occurrences are expected

```js
var regex = /\[[^\][]*\]|\b(\d+)\b/ig;
var str = '1234 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123';
var res = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1]) res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would seek and remove the square-bracket-delimited substrings and then do a match for all bounded strings of digits... something like this:

```
var string = '1234 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123';

string.replace(/\[.+?\]/g, '').match(/\b\d+\b/g);
  // => ["1234", "67890", "212123"]
```

Comment: The difference here is that the `/\[.+?\]/g` won't match if there are linebreak symbols in-between `[` and `]`. That is why I stick to negated character classes.

Comment: This is true, in which case I would replace `/\[.+?\]/g` with `/\[[\s\S]+?\]/g`.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do as follows;

```js
var str = "1234 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123",
 result = str.match(/\d+(?=\s*\[|$)/g);
console.log(result);
```

```
\d+(?=\s*\[|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/ILpZE1H51rQaF6LU)

Comment: It works!
Also I modified to add [ ] to 'nude' numbers:

str4 = "1234 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123";
str4.replace(/(\d+)(?=\s*\[|$)/g,"[$1]");

And it seems the problem is solved completely!
But I don't understand your pattern :)

Comment: @Sam Aniston The pattern uses a look ahead `(?=)`. It looks ahead for a `\s*`(0 or more white spaces) followed by a `\[` (right square bracket) or `|` for an end of line `$` --> `(?=\s*\[|$)` and collects all decimals `\d+` in front of them globally. I am glad you solved your problem.

Comment: This is faulty and will break if input is `1234 bla171819 [ blabla 101112 ] 67890 [113141516 ] bla171819 212123`

Comment: @anubhava The given string pattern is the base here. It will also break if you apply it on `"please i want [to see 1234] you 6543break"` string.

Comment: `\d+(?=\s*\[|$)` won't work if there is no whitespace and a square bracket right after these digits in the string and if the digits are not at the end of the string.